# Opencv 4x2 webcams

Tags: python, opencv

I wanna make 4x2 webcams in opencv but I can't get.
That is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while True:
    _,frame = cap.read()
    w = int(cap.get(4))
    h = int(cap.get(4))
    img = np.zeros(frame.shape, np.uint8)

    small_web = cv2.resize(frame, (0, 0), fx=0.25, fy=0.5)

    img[:h//2, :w - 2] = small_web
    img[:h//2, w - 2: w - 1] = small_web
    img[:h//2, w - 1: w - 0] = small_web
    img[:h//2, w - 0:] = small_web

    img[h//2: , :w - 2] = small_web
    img[h//2:, w - 2: w - 1] = small_web
    img[h//2:, w - 1: w - 0] = small_web
    img[h//2:, w - 0:] = small_web
    
    cv2.imshow("IMG", img)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) == 'n':
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

My error I got is:
img[:h//2, :w - 2] = small_web
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (240,160,3) into shape (240,478,3)

If anything is more easier than that, show me a demo.

Comment: why are you resizing your image to 0.15 for the x axis? if you want 2 images in this axis it should be 0.5, if you want 4 it should be 0.25. Where does the 0.15 come from?

Comment: Sorry, I'm wrong that point but I still get an error " could not broadcast input array from shape (240,160,3) into shape (240,478,3) " though I change fx=0.25. How can I fix it?

Comment: please edit your question with the code you tried and the exact error you are getting

Comment: you are doing `w = int(cap.get(4))` and `h = int(cap.get(4))`. both h and w are getting the same index. are you sure this is correct? also why are you doing w-2, w-1 and w-0? why not w//2 as you do with h? it's difficult to understand why you do certain things in your code.

Comment: I assume w = 4 and h = 4 in above code. So I wanna make 4x2 my webcams. First I divide 
 h(height) two parts which can be called two rows so it becomes 2, 2. Second I need to divide w(weight) 4 parts in each row. So I do  :w - 2 (: 4-2) result is :2 so I get my first 0.25 x 0.5 webcam and I do the same things in w - 2: w -1 so 4 - 2: 4 -1. That is 2: 3 so I get second webcam and so on. I do the same way to get others 2 webcam in a row.

Comment: It might be confusing. If I made u confused, I'm sorry.